# Android Checkbox listener method is called right after the screen rotation

Tags: android, checkbox, rotation, screen

I'm starting to program android app and I'm having a problem with a checkbox.

I've got a checkbox in my activity, i put a log message in the OnCheckedChanged method to be launched when the checkbox is checked, but when I rotate the screen the message appears again as if the OnCheckedChanged method was call automatically when the system destroys and creates the activity again.

What is happening??  thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The best and cleanest solution I have used multiple times is to check if View.isPressed(). This makes sense since the user will be pressing on the Switch when it triggers the callback.

```
private Switch.OnCheckedChangeListener mOnSwitch = new Switch.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if (!buttonView.isPressed())
        {
            // Not from user!
            return;
        }

        // Handle user check change
    }
};
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: @Mitch So to understand the issue... When you change the Switch state after the app rotates the callback will be triggered. You have two options. 1. Don't attach the listener until you set the switch state. 2. Do a check for actual user press as in the example above.

Answer (score 8):

I have been gone through such problem once. it was so frustrating finally i remove OnCheckedChangedListener and replace it with onClickListener.
In onclick methode i use c.IsChecked().

My guess is that android call onCheckChange whenever checkbox state is changed either by user of through code (by c.setchecked(boolean)),

In your case c.setchecked(boolean) methode called internally by android to restore UI state.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you for idea!

Comment: This is the cleanest and most elegant solution. It is a pity that the android team can not fix such a thing for 10 years.

Comment: onClickListener doesnt pass on the checked/unchecked state of the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as somebody already mentioned, it is possible to detect who launched the 'change of state' event by using isPressed method, i.e. it responds only to user action.
However there is a problem with Switch control which, apart from clicking, can also be dragged left or right which also changes the state but isPressed method doesn't detect that. I was hoping to find in the Switch class a method perhaps called isDragged, but there is nothing.

It's sort of hard to believe that they forgot to implement such a thing so probably I'm missing something.

Answer (score -4):

Try adding following lines in your manifest file in application tag:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

also [read this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges) , this will solve your problem.

Comment: That's a hack, not a solution.

Comment: Well do you know the solution? I had a similar situation and it worked for me.

Comment: @CommonsWare answered the OP's particular question. My solution (for a slightly different issue) was to disable saveEnabled since I was reusing a `CheckBox` with the same `id` (which Android uses to save state), but setting the state manually when created (therefore I did not need any automatic state saving). Your solution to disable config changes and restarting the `Activity` doesn't solve the problem, if the `Activity` is destroyed for memory purposes (just leaving the app for long enough), the `Activity` will be destroyed and recreated, and the original problem will still be there.

Comment: it's like shot a mosquito with a rocket launcher. Checking `if (compoundButton.isPressed())` in the callback, if not ignore it